# Extend inherited prototype method in Javascript

Tags: javascript, inheritance, methods, prototype, extend

I have some classes (constructors) that are related as "parent-child":

```
// Abstract root SuperClass

function SuperClass() {
    this.CLASS_ID = "SUPER-CLASS";
    throw new Error('Failed to instantiate abstract class' + this.CLASS_ID);
}

SuperClass.prototype.sayHello = function() {
    alert('Hello, world!');
};

// Absctract ClassA inherits from SuperClass
// inherit() and extend() are generic functions from the David Flanagan`s 
// brilliand book "Definitive Guide"

function ClassA() {
    this.CLASS_ID = "CLASS-A";
    throw new Error('Failed to instantiate abstract class' + this.CLASS_ID);
}

ClassA.prototype = inherit(SuperClass.prototype);

// Concrete ClassB inherits from ClassA

function ClassB(initData) {
    this.CLASS_ID = "CLASS-B";
}

ClassB.prototype = inherit(ClassA.prototype);

extend(ClassB.prototype, {
    constructor: ClassB,

    welcomeNewDay: function() {
        this.sayHello();
        this.doSomethingElse();
    },

    doSomethingElse: function(){
        alert('Jumping');
    }
});

var classB = new ClassB();
classB.welcomeNewDay();
```

How can I correctly extend method `.sayHello()` of the abstract `ClassA` without overloading it?

I`ve tried to make it this way:

```
extend(ClassA.prototype, {
    sayHello: function() {
        this.__proto__.sayHello();
        this.sing();
    },

    sing: function() {
        alert('Lalala');
    }
});
```

The problem is that `.sing()` is invoked 3 times instead of 1.

If I try:

```
this.__proto__.sayHello.call(this);
```

It throws an exception:

> Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Comment: sayHello()  is not method of the abstract ClassA .It is inherited from its prototype

Comment: Sometime you use `inherit` and sometime use prototype.Why?Is there any requirements ?

Comment: @RIYAJKHAN I use inherit() when I need to get (copy) all possible methods from the ancestor class prototype. I used prototype (here I guess? `SuperClass.prototype.sayHello"`) just to quick type new method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to access the initial class:

```
extend(ClassA.prototype, {
    sayHello: function() {
        SuperClass.prototype.sayHello.call(this);
        this.sing();
    },

    sing: function() {
        alert('Lalala');
    }
});
```

or just store the current `sayHello()` method:

```
var initialSayHello = ClassA.prototype.sayHello;
extend(ClassA.prototype, {
    sayHello: function() {
        initialSayHello.call(this);
        this.sing();
    },

    sing: function() {
        alert('Lalala');
    }
});
```

You need to have the reference to the original `sayHello()` method.

---

> Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

It is thrown because you actually have an infinite recursion, calling the method itself in the method.

Comment: Dmitri, thank you for yor help. I see you`ve suggested to hardcode the link to the ancestor prototype method and it works. Can I resolve the same problem without the explicit writing the class name in the first case?

Comment: @J.P.Remarg You need to access somehow the prototype, and using the Constructor is ok. But it would be something weird: `this.__proto__.__proto__.sayHello.call(this)`.